# Algolia instantsearch pagination not working

Tags: react-native, pagination, expo, algolia, instantsearch.js

`refine()` is not working in react-native

```
const InfiniteHits = ({ hits, hasMore, refine }) => {
  return <FlatList
    data={hits}
    keyExtractor={item => item.objectID}
    onEndReached={() => refine()}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <CardListingItem item={item}/> 
    )}
  />
}
```

I tried another alternative using `connectPagination` also not working:

```
const Pagination = ({refine}) => {
  return <Button
    title="more"
    onPress={() => refine()}
  />
}
export const ConnectedPagination = connectPagination(Pagination)
```

Version:

```
  "algoliasearch": "^3.33.0", 
  "react-instantsearch-native": "^5.6.0",
```

what's the problem ?

Comment: I know I can't pass the function as a factor. Where is the function you want to use defined?

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issue?

Comment: nope. still can't figure out the problem